# How to validate numeric inputs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, validation

In Django you can easily use MinValueValidator and MaxValueValidator to validate IntergerFields.
What is the their counterparts in ReactJS?
I have a form in the frontend (built with ReactJS) where multiple fields are type=number fields and the numbers need to fit inside a specific range of values, i.e. greater than 0, smaller than 250.
In the backend, I achieved this control over the numeric input by using Min/Max ValueValidator. What shall I do in ReactJS frontend?

Thank you!

Comment: If you use redux-form, it has a validation for your form field https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/syncvalidation/. If you do not use redux-form, you have to have an onChange handler to check wether the value is in the range or not. If it is not valid, you can set state form is invalid and disable submit event

Comment: I think you should try redux-form if you use redux in your app

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at redux-form as well!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can still use the `min` and `max` attributes for the `input`, but have some custom logic for checking that the `input` value doesn't go outside of that interval.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  handleChange = event => {
    let { value, min, max } = event.target;
    value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));

    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="250"
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How about if I need a field with decimal places? Such currency fields? I am struggling with this for hours and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Value doesn't have to be`int` in anyway

Comment: With this solution you are not able to delete 1 so you can not enter anything that does not start with 1.