# React input validation with onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, input

I have a numeric input, which I want to validate with an onChange, but when said input is cleared, react throws `ReferenceError: value is not defined` which is understandable - it has nothing to validate.

I'm using this approach [[Answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770246/how-to-validate-numeric-inputs-in-reactjs)

I'm using functional components and here is my code snippet:

```js
   const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
        userTeamChosen: "",
        eventNumber: 0,
        value: 0,
        ethValue: 0})

    function handleNumeric(event) {
        const { name, checkedValue, min, max } = event.target
        value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {...prevFormData,[name]: checkedValue}})}

    <input
        type="number"
        name="value"
        value={formData.value}
        onChange={handleNumeric}
        min="5"
        max="10000000"/>
```

How should I change my validation, to keep in onChange, but without erroring, when the input is empty?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value variable? which is getting assigned Math.max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a `checkedValue` property in the number `input` element, Use `valueAsNumber` or `value` instead.

```
function handleNumeric(event) {
    const { name, valueAsNumber, min, max } = event.target
    const result = Math.max(+min, Math.min(+max, !Number.isNaN(valueAsNumber) ? valueAsNumber : +min));
    setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {...prevFormData,[name]: result}})}
```

Comment: You really should not be changing the formData directly (ie: `formData.value`) when using React `useState`. You should only use the function provided by `useState`, in this case `setFormData`  This solution simply writes over the `formData` variable directly which coerces any possible NaN cases, thus hiding errors. The error is avoided because  when you try to access it in the `setFormData`, it was already coerced. Better to check for NaN before calling setFormData.

Comment: Yes, I know about setting`state` by `setState`, but I missed it because I get the code by copying and pasting, Thanks for notifying me about `valueAsNumber` I didn't know about it producing `NaN` if the `input` with an empty value. I just update it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were very close to solving this one yourself :D

The only errors I noticed were the value variables not being declared or defined anywhere, to solve this I just added formData so that react would know that it's the formData's value being used and not some random value

```
function handleNumeric(event) {
    const { name, checkedValue, min, max } = event.target
    formData.value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(formData.value)));
    setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {...prevFormData,[name]: checkedValue}})}
```

Comment: This solved the inital problem, but caused more errors down the line, solution below fully solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

A number input is considered valid when empty. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number. So if you empty the input and try to check `valueAsNumber` it will return NaN. You can check for this case using `isNaN()`:

```
    function handleNumeric(event) {
        const { name, checkedValue, min, max } = event.target
        if (isNaN(checkedValue)) checkedValue = 0;
        value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(checkedValue)));
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {...prevFormData,[name]: checkedValue}})}
```

Other than that, your solution should be working fine in all other cases. Placing a required attribute on the number input may help as well since it will ask the browser to prevent users from emptying the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```js
 function handleNumeric(event) {
        const { name, checkedValue, min, max } = event.target
        formData.value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(formData.value)));
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {...prevFormData,[name]: checkedValue}})}
```